# Why does using string.split() on a string of length one where the delimiter is the same as the string value return an array of length two

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, replace

I have the following code where I'm trying to split a file path by '/' character

```
setFilePath(props.filePath.split('/'));
```

If the file path that is passed in is '/', so the same as the separator, it returns a array

```
["", ""]
```

Could some explain why using string.split() on a string that is the same as the separator returns an array of two instead of one? How do I get it to return only an array of length one. My workaround was to use slice the string before splitting it

```
setFilePath(props.filePath.slice(0,-1).splice('/'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a string of length 0 followed by a slash followed by a string of length 0, so the result makes sense given a certain understanding of what split does. This is a pretty common problem we've all encountered when it comes to string splitting. The technique I generally use to discard empties is to do a split followed by a filter:

```
setFilePath(
  props.filePath.split('/').filter(s => s.length > 0)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Split - 
If separator appears at the beginning (or end) of the string, it still has the effect of splitting.  The result is an empty (i.e. zero length) string, which appears at the first (or last) position of the returned array. [#collected from mozilla.org]

So in your case - **Both first and last character is the separator itself**
 - **First** entry in array - an empty string as -separator is **first** character
 - **Last** entry in array - an empty string as -separator is **last** character

//Hope this will help